# can there be fractional values in the Veblen hierarchy?

Tags: ordinals, analytic-continuation

I know that $\varphi_0(0)=\omega$ and $\varphi_1(0)=\epsilon_0$, but what would the value of $\varphi_{\frac{1}{2}}(0)$ be. it seems intuitive that it would be smaller than $\epsilon_0$, being $$\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_0,\epsilon_{-1},\epsilon_{-\omega},\epsilon_{-\epsilon_0},\epsilon_{-\Gamma_0} etc...$$  but all of these I would assume should be larger than $\varphi_{\frac{1}{2}}(0)$

Comment: None of the expressions $\varphi_{1\over 2}(0)$, ${1\over 2}\epsilon_0$, $\epsilon_{-1}$, etc. mean anything. Division and subtraction just aren't meaningful in this setting.

Comment: Great Noah. that answers my question